# Quantum mechanics, what is the exact definition of an observer?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, terminology, definition, observers

Ik there are two other questions regarding this but I couldn't really find an answer

For example in the electron double split experiment.

How do I have to measure the electrons so that my measurement counts as measurement?

What if I delete every record of the measured values after I measured them? I mean its kinda like they never got measured in the first place then.

What if a measurement never changes anything? So I have the values of a measurement stored on a hard drive but I never view them is that still measuring them?

I mean the particle can't know if the measurement will be used in the future but still.

I mean this question is kinda unanswerable because if I delete every record of the measurement I can't know what actually happened. But I'm hoping there's some other way to know that?

Also im not too into physics so as long as that can still explain my question please provide a simple answer

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/530761/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Thx i found my anwere there.
Can you repost the comment as an answere so I can mark as solved?

Comment: see:  Peres A. *When is a quantum measurement?* American Journal of Physics. 1986 Aug;54(8):688-92.